# How do I mask the route path in vue while passing data through params?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parameters

[image]

I managed to pass an object through params. However, how do I mask the information in the url shown above?

[image]
Here's the code where I pushed the object through using params into another page called 'Staff Profile'.

[image]

This is the path when I added the parameter.

Comment: You can't and you'd need to keep data somewhere in the app where view component can access it, e.g. global store. It's unknown why "id" became serialized object in your case, this is possibly a mistake

Comment: @EstusFlask hmm what do you meant by keeping the data somewhere in the app? My data is kept in data(){ return{...}}

Comment: "e.g. global store". Check how they work if you didn't yet.

Comment: What do you mean by masking? What is your concern, specifically? What information are you trying to hide and from whom?

Comment: @taomy concern is that i do not want to show the long string of details in the URL